# XSLT:- Cannot load input file 'filepath/myfile.xml'

Tags: xml, xslt, altova

I am trying to transform xml file using xslt but getting below error

**Cannot load input file 'file:///C:/testTarn.xml'**

if I delete some child elements, it processes file successfully.

My xml file has some 9000 rows and sizes around 350 kb.

My test Xslt does nothing except copy source file as shown below.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:gmt="http://gmt/Schema/TradeCommodity/1" xmlns:cs="urn:cs" exclude-result-prefixes="gmt cs msxsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! There is no place in your xslt that would refer to your testTarn.xml file or any file access at all. At what point should that error happen? If it's the input file to your transform then maybe another application still has the file open (trying to write the many rows)?

Comment: I can see this is Altova specific problem as transformation is working fine with visual studio editor.

Comment: Is there more to this error? Additional details? An error number? "Cannot load input file" could mean anything.

Comment: @Tomalak: thanks for reply. Below is exact error:-                                                                                                Cannot load input file :///C:/.../testTarn.xml'
 Details
  cvc-attribute.5: Value 'gmt:TradedInstrument' of attribute 'xsi:type' must resolve to a type definition.
  cvc-assess-elt.2: Assessment of attribute 'xsi:type' failed.
  cvc-assess-elt: Lax assessment of element <gmt:Instrument> failed.
  ALXT0006: Cannot load input file 'file:///C:/.../testTarn.xml'

Comment: @StefanHegny : thanks for reply. I am using Altova XML Spy and they have feature where you can refer xslt directly without providing path in xml. File is not referenced any other process. As I mentioned it works for smaller size file.

Comment: thanks everyone, it was sorted out using visual studio xml editor although problem still exists with Altova.